# is there a way of configuring a ms compiler?

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-code

I have visual studio code installed. however, I do not want to use a third party c++ compiler. is there a way of getting the Microsoft c++ compiler and configuring it to visual studio code without a full version of visual studio?

Comment: Visual Studio Code doesn't come with a compiler, so *every* compiler is "third-party", including Microsoft C++. Why not use Visual Studio itself if you want an IDE for C++?

Comment: I do not have enough disk space to install a full visual studio version on my on the go laptop.

Comment: Microsoft's C++ compiler only comes with the whole suite, though you can do a "Custom Install" to trim that down. `clang` is generally a lot smaller, so unless you absolutely need Microsoft's C++ compiler, I'd use that if you're short on space.

Comment: ok. thanks very  much.